# Multiple countdown timers on one page with JQuery

Tags: jquery, timer

I am creating a tiny game in JQuery that needs two types of countdown timers, each of which will be re-used on each level of the game, and so needs clear/re-set to an original value.

```
 -Timer One: Countdown from 5 seconds then call gameLevel.
 -Timer Two: Countdown from 60 seconds and then call levelOver.
```

I am trying to do this without reaching for the Keith Wood plug-in because I have a bunch of other game-related stuff going on in the countdown functions so I want to keep it as transparent-to-me as possible.

Here's Timer One, which works fine:

```
//5 second countdown to game start
var counter=setInterval(levelStartTime, 1000);
var $level_start_time = 5;

function levelStartTime() {
    $level_start_time = $level_start_time-1;
    if ($level_start_time <= 0)
      {
        clearInterval(counter);
        gameLevel($level);
        return;
      }
    $('.level-start-time span').text($level_start_time);
  }
```

Of course if I try to simply duplicate this for Timer Two I get all kinds of maths wackyness. Can anyone suggest a restructure that will let me have two countdowns in my page, or point me to a demo doing a similar thing?

Comment: The problem with intervals is they don't actually run at the exact intervals you specify. If you want it to be more exact, reduce the interval time and use the Date object to compare times. You could then handle both timers with a single interval.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) commented, you could do something like using a small interval time:

```
var counter = setInterval(levelStartTime, 100); // Small interval.
var $level_start_time = new Date(date.getTime() + 5000);

function levelStartTime() {
    if ($level_start_time >= date.getTime())
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
        gameLevel($level);
        return;
    }
    $('.level-start-time span').text($level_start_time);
}
```